# Magento 2.3.2 Why Advance Reporting in coupon code and customer id weird

Tags: magento2.3.2, advanced-reporting

i have showing default magento *advance reporting* in 
orders tab and customer tab in **customer id** and **coupon code** looks weired?

I want to **correct data** here 
How can do this?
[image]
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.